# maven does not include fxml file

Tags: java, maven

I try to create a maven project of a java program, which includes two java classes and a fxml file, which are all located in the same directory (src/main/java/package).
When i install the project with maven it does not copy the fxml file into the .jar file so that the program does not work any more. A few hours ago I basically created an equivalent project and everything worked fine.

How can I fix that?

Comment: @Nik The question is fine.   This problem is not uncommon for Eclipse programmers learning Maven.

Answer (score -1):

The Maven convention is that Java files go in `src/main/java`.  Any non-Java files go in `src/main/resources`.

The Eclipse emulation of Maven does not make this distinction.  Both directories are source folders which is incorrect but "good enough" to handle correct Maven projects.

So, move your file to the correct location.